# Where do I deduct convention registration expenses?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

My wife does direct sales as a home business and I am trying to figure out the proper place to deduct the expense of a convention registration associated with that business. It seems to me that there are two options:

Option 1: Schedule C Line 24: Travel, Meals, and Entertainment (The convention involves travel so the rest of the trip would be deducted here. It seems to make sense to lump the registration fee in here too.)

Option 2: Schedule C Line 27: Other Expenses. If there is specific line for the expense then it is supposed to end up here, so it seems to make sense to deduct the registration fee here.

I can't find any direct guidance stating where to deduct it. Can anyone help?